# Azure data factory binary copy from FTP

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-data-factory

I have copy activity that does a binary copy of .zip file from FTP to ADLS.
Everything works well, i managed to copy 6 files, and when i needed to copy .zip file which size is 4GB it thorws me an error remote server error 530 - not logged in. Does anybody know what can cause this?

[image]

Comment: May it be that the ftp server closes the session before the transfer is complete? Maybe it is too slow? Try testing the throughput of your ftp server

Comment: Hi Martin, again :).
The copy activity throws me an error after 1 min. I managed to copy a file with WINSCP, with few reconnects. Its an external source so i am very limited with options about FTP. I was wondering if this is something with ADF.

Comment: Hey there! Didn't realize it was you asking. Try with different values on the policy property of the activity. You can configure retry and retryIntervalInSeconds. More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#activity-json

Comment: Yeah, this looks like it could help. I saw that WinSCP also timeouts but it has own retry policy. I will try and i will get to you. 
Thanks Martin.

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried this and problem is when connection drop retry policy start again copy activity but it starts to copy a file from beginning again, it doesn't  continue copying file when it's stop (for example it dropped at 550mb, retry policy with copy files from beginning)

Comment: Yes, it will always start from the beginning :( there is no way to make it start from where it failed. Maybe you can talk this with the ftp admin? Or ask for the zip file to be split into smaller parts

Answer (score 0):

Copy Activity level retry will always start from beginning, but there's also retry inner a Copy Activity which will resume from break point. If a Copy finally failed, it means the break point resume also failed.
Could you provide a RunID for troubleshooting?

Regards,
Gary

Comment: sorry i didn't see your comment. I got some infos that in the future there will be an auto-resume option, but don't know ETA.